# Products menu in firefox scrolls with page

Tags: bug, design, products-menu

On Firefox 74.0 I click the Products tab on the main site and scroll down the page and notice the menu goes with the page.

I found this while trying the new dark mode.

[image]

Comment: I see this also without dark mode.